# Grails, Jobs, Static Helper Methods and Hibernate Session

Tags: java, hibernate, session, grails, quartz-scheduler

I have a Grails job-class (`grails-app/jobs`) who needs to call a static (helper) method (defined in `src/groovy`). This method calls get- and find-methods respectively on 2 different domain-objects. The result of the method call is returning a simple `String` (could return anything for that sake - doesn't matter).

My question is, how do I use `.withTransaction` or `.withSession` in the job-class when I'm calling a static method containing fetch of 2 (could be more) different domain-classes?

Or, how do I declare/use a Hibernate session in a job-class so that I don't have to use .withBlaBla?

**EDIT (another EDIT at the bottom - sorry):**
The lines where EZTable and EZRow is fetched is working. EmailReminder I had to wrap with EmailReminder.with... Now the lines with call to `ServiceUtils.handleSubjectOrMessageString(ezTable, ezRow, emailReminder.subject)` are causing an exception (this is added "now" - the entire job-class was working earlier with simple String-values).

```
class EmailReminderJob implements Job {

    EmailReminder emailReminder
    EZTable ezTable
    EZRow ezRow

    static triggers = {}

    def void execute(JobExecutionContext context) {
        List<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>(0)

        ezTable = EZTable.get(new Long(context.mergedJobDataMap.get('ezTableId')))
        ezRow = EZRow.get(new Long(context.mergedJobDataMap.get('ezRowId')))
        EmailReminder.withTransaction { status ->
            emailReminder = EmailReminder.get(new Long(context.mergedJobDataMap.get('emailReminderId')))
            if(emailReminder.sendMessageToOwnerUser && emailReminder.ownerUser.email!=null)
                emails.add(emailReminder.ownerUser.email)
            if(emailReminder.sendMessageToOwnerCompany && emailReminder.ownerCompany.email!=null)
                emails.add(emailReminder.ownerCompany.email)
            if(emailReminder.emails!=null && emails.size()>0)
                emails.addAll(new ArrayList<String>(emailReminder.emails))
            if(emailReminder.messageReceiverUsers!=null && emailReminder.messageReceiverUsers.size()>0) {
                for(user in emailReminder.messageReceiverUsers) {
                    if(user.email!=null)
                        emails.add(user.email)
                }
            }
        }

        if(emails.size()>0) {
            String host = "localhost";
            Properties properties = System.getProperties();
            properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
            try{
                // Create a default MimeMessage object.
                MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(emailReminder.emailFrom));
                for(email in emails) {
                    message.addRecipient(
                        Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        new InternetAddress(email)
                    );
                }
                message.setSubject(ServiceUtils.handleSubjectOrMessageString(ezTable, ezRow, emailReminder.subject));
                message.setText(ServiceUtils.handleSubjectOrMessageString(ezTable, ezRow, emailReminder.definedMessage));
                Transport.send(message);
            }catch (MessagingException mex) {
                mex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The static-method in my util-class under `src/groove` (the line `EZColumn ezcolumn = EZColumn.get(id)` and the next are causing the exception):

```
def static String handleSubjectOrMessageString(EZTable eztable, EZRow ezrow, String subjectOrMessage) {
    String regex = '(?<=\\$\\$)(.*?)(?=\\$\\$)'
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex)
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(subjectOrMessage)
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    while(matcher.find()) {
        if(subjectOrMessage.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()).contains('#')) {
            String stringId = subjectOrMessage.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()).split('#')[0]
            String name = subjectOrMessage.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()).split('#')[1]
            try {
                Long id = new Long(stringId)
                EZColumn ezcolumn = EZColumn.get(id)
                EZCell ezcell = EZCell.findByEzTableAndEzRowAndEzColumn(eztable, ezrow, ezcolumn)
                matcher.appendReplacement(stringBuffer, fetchCellValues(ezcell, ezcolumn))
            } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
                if(stringId.equals("id")) {
                    if(name.equals("row"))
                        matcher.appendReplacement(stringBuffer, ezrow.id.toString())
                    else if(name.equals("table"))
                        matcher.appendReplacement(stringBuffer, eztable.id.toString())
                    else
                        matcher.appendReplacement(stringBuffer, "???")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    matcher.appendTail(stringBuffer);
    println stringBuffer.toString().replaceAll('\\$', "")
    return stringBuffer.toString().replaceAll('\\$', "")
}
```

The exception:

```
| Error 2015-02-11 10:33:33,954 [quartzScheduler_Worker-1] ERROR core.JobRunShell  - Job EmailReminderGroup.ER_3_EZTable_3 threw an unhandled Exception: 
Message: null
   Line | Method
->> 202 | run in org.quartz.core.JobRunShell
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
^   573 | run in org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread
| Error 2015-02-11 10:33:33,996 [quartzScheduler_Worker-1] ERROR core.ErrorLogger  - Job (EmailReminderGroup.ER_3_EZTable_3 threw an exception.
Message: Job threw an unhandled exception.
   Line | Method
->> 213 | run in org.quartz.core.JobRunShell
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
^   573 | run in org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread
Caused by NullPointerException: null
->> 202 | run in org.quartz.core.JobRunShell
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
^   573 | run in org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread
| Error 2015-02-11 10:33:34,005 [quartzScheduler_Worker-1] ERROR listeners.ExceptionPrinterJobListener  - Exception occurred in job: null
Message: org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception: java.lang.NullPointerException]
   Line | Method
->> 218 | run in org.quartz.core.JobRunShell
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
^   573 | run in org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread
Caused by SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception.
->> 213 | run in org.quartz.core.JobRunShell
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
^   573 | run in org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread
Caused by NullPointerException: null
->> 202 | run in org.quartz.core.JobRunShell
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
^   573 | run in org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread
```

**EDIT AGAIN :( :**
I have many nested calls in my static method (`fetchCellValues(ezcell, ezcolumn)` in the `matcher.appendReplacement(stringBuffer, fetchCellValues(ezcell, ezcolumn))`-method is calling deeper to fetch values and I actually get a "no Session"-exception at one call (call regular as all the other calls trying to fetch another domain-object):

```
Message: org.quartz.SchedulerException: Job threw an unhandled exception. [See nested exception: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session]
```

Comment: Note: I also tried declaring the job `@Transactional` although documentation says: "Jobs are configured by default to have Hibernate Session bounded to thread each time job is executed" https://grails.org/Job+Scheduling+%28Quartz%29

Comment: I stuck with the same problem. I fix the session adding `attach()` of the domain before using my personal service.

Answer (score 1):

You use them like you would anywhere. Both are independent of the class they're called on; `withTransaction` just runs the wrapped code in a transaction, joining a current active transaction if there is one, and `withSession` makes the current Hibernate `Session` available to the wrapped code but otherwise doesn't do anything.

You don't indicate any reason for needing either, so it's not obvious what to advise specifically. You don't need a transaction if you're only reading data, and if you're calling domain class methods you shouldn't need access to the session.

One use for `withTransaction` that I've advocated in the past (pretty much the only use for it since it's typically misused) is to avoid lazy loading exceptions when there isn't an active session already. Wrapping code in a `withTransaction` block has the side effect of creating a session and keeping it open for the duration of the block and that lets you work with lazy-loaded instances and collections. Controllers have an active session because there's an open-session-in-view interceptor that starts a session at the beginning of the request, stores it in a `ThreadLocal`, and flushes and closes it at the end of the request. Jobs are similar because the plugin uses Quartz job start/end events to do the same thing.

But whether you are making your code transactional because of lazy loading or because you're updating, you should usually be doing the work in a transactional service.

Services are great for transactional work because they're transactional by default (only services that have no `@Transactional` annotations and include `static transactional = false` are non-transactional), and it's easy to configure transaction demarcation per-class and per-method with the `@Transactional` annotation. They are also great for encapsulating business logic, independent of how they're called; there's usually no need for a service method to have any HTTP/Job/etc. awareness, just pass it the data needed in String/number/boolean/object arguments and let it do its work.

I like to keep controllers simple, doing data binding from the request params and calling services to do the real work, then rendering a response or routing to the next page, and I do the same thing in Quartz jobs. Use Quartz for its scheduling functionality, but do the real work in a service. Dependency-inject the service like any bean (`def fooService`) and put all of the business logic and database work there. It keeps things  cleanly delineated in the code, and makes testing easier since you can test the service methods without having to mock HTTP calls or Quartz.

Comment: Hi Burt - first of all, a huge thanks for your time. All though I've created many "small" web-apps in many different frameworks the past many years, I've come to like Grails the most. And your name seems to be the last I stumble upon whenever reading a useful answer/article. Your time is very well appreciated. Thank you! Although above answer didn't help me directly, I got to understand the mindset you share in splitting up your app wisely.

Comment: I must say, I tried calling a service from the job-class but met the same challenge, and I think it's because I have some calls on domain-objects lazy-loading data. I will sure try the service-usage again - let me get back. Meanwhile, I'll try to post some code that I've done which is challenging me. It's the first time I'm using StackOverflow - hopefully I can figure this out :)

Comment: Alright, now I converted both my util-classes having lots of static methods into Service-classes in Grails. In my job-class I've now defined `def serviceUtilsService` in order to get it injected into the job-class and call the same now non-static methods (`serviceUtilsService.handleSubjectOrMessageString(ezTable, ezRow, emailReminder.subject)`) - but now I'm getting a null-exception on the `serviceUtilsService`-object :( It seems lots have tried this and it always was a definition-error - i.e. name of object not correct. I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is that a class-scope field, or a method variable? It has to be a field in order to work with dependency injection. Also the name looks wrong, do you really have 'service' in the class name twice? The bean name of `FooService` is `fooService`, so that's only correct of the class name is `ServiceUtilsService`.

Comment: Yes Burt, class-scope and the name is the way you wrote. Here is a snippet of the job-class:
`
class EmailReminderJob implements Job {

 def sessionRequired = true
 def ServiceUtilsService serviceUtilsService
 EmailReminder emailReminder
 EZTable ezTable
 EZRow ezRow
 
    static triggers = {}

    def void execute(JobExecutionContext context) {
  List<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>(0)
  ...
...
     message.setSubject(serviceUtilsService.handleSubjectOrMessageString(ezTable, ezRow, emailReminder.subject));

`
I even tried as mentioned in the documentation:
`def serviceUtilsService`